# Invariant Violation: Native component for "RNSVGSvgView" does not exist

Tags: ios, svg, react-native, react-native-ios

After days of research on the internet I still haven't solved my problem yet.
I am using react-native-svg and I am having the same issues:
[No component found for view with the name "RNSVGPath"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7oht.png)

Or this one:
[Invariant Violation: Native component for "RNSVGSvgView" does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2MtA.png)

I tried a lot of things, including:

```
react-native unlink react-native-svg
npm uninstall react-native-svg
npm install react-native-svg
react-native link react-native-svg
react-native run-ios
```

Also:

```
pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
react-native run-ios
```

But still nothing...
Here's the versions I am using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.50.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^6.0.1-rc.1"
}
```

I tried to build it from XCode directly and still nothing...

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try to do this:

```
npm install react-native-svg --save //(again)
react-native link react-native-svg //(again)
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

Then in another terminal

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Before starting your ios app with react-native run-ios, you have to add libRNSVG.a manually to your Linked Frameworks and Libraries in Xcode

And then ... Tada

Comment: For android it was working, but for ios, unfortunatly, not

Answer (score 5):

SVG Problem, I also stuffed 4 hours and get the solution.

**Automatic link:**

```
react-native link react-native-svg
```

Does not work automatically then you do with manually.

**Manual Link:**

1 Append the following lines to `android/settings.gradle:`

```
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,  '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
```

2 Insert the following lines inside the dependencies block in `android/app/build.gradle:`

```
implementation project(':react-native-svg')
```

3 Open up `android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java

- Add `import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;` to the imports at the top of the file.
- Add `new SvgPackage()` to the list returned by the `getPackages()` method. Add a comma to the previous item if there's already something there.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because "react-native link" is broken as of RN 0.51. Linking manually after complete removal and reinstall fixed it on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Svg have problem with version

first, unlink svg then remove npm of svg then  install new one

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-svg": "5.1.8"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
The problem is that we just upgraded to react-native 0.50.3 and don't want to go back to an old version.
Is there an other solution ?

Comment: Actually svg package has a list of dependenc listed for supporting version of react native go through documents

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but on Android.

So, if you are in the same conditions, here is something that fixed it, the trouble happened specifically on MainApplication, so you want to look at :

- open `android/app/src/java/com/*/MainApplication.java`
- add `import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;` on top with other imports
- add `new SvgPackage()` along the others in the list `getPackages()` (~line 30-ish)

Answer (score 0):

I was having huge problems with something similar and, after much investigation, realised that the issue was simply due to an  being nested in a . When I wrapped the  in a  my errors all disappeared. Not sure if that helps but thought it worth mentioning on the off-chance.